# How to "tail" the modsecurity logfile until a certain timestamp?

Tags: regex, grep, tail, mod-security, mod-security2

I have a modsecurity logfile where I want to get the last events until a certain timestamp.
A short introduction in how modsecurity logfiles are assembled:
for example, 1 event is presented like:

```
--8b014015-A--
[16/Mar/2016:20:13:02 +0100]
...omitted... 
--8b014015-B--
...omitted... 
--8b014015-F--
...omitted... 
--8b014015-H--
...omitted... 
--8b014015-Z--
```

A full example can be found here http://pastebin.com/M1iqnY6L

I was thinking to combine tail and grep.

1. grep to find the line of the timestamp (lets call this line *timestampLine*)
2. *tailLines* = (total lines in the file) - (*timestampLine* + 1)
   //+ 1 because a request has the first line with `--id-A--` and second line the timestamp
3. tail -n $*tailLines* logfile.log

Is there a better way? If not, how do I grep this timestamp and get the line-number from step 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print};/\[16\/Mar\/2016:20:13:02/ {exit}' logfile
```